# smarty name of variable dynamic

Tags: templates, smarty, variable-assignment, template-engine

I'm studying smarty for about two months and I find myself be in front of a problem.

I am creating a dynamic menu that reads the configuration from a file called submenu.conf in this file are:

```
tot_sub_menu_2 = "2"
text_sub_menu_2_1 = "Home"
text_sub_menu_2_2 = "about"
```

tpl file in my application I wish he would create the menu dynamically in this way:

```
{for $foo=1 to #tot_sub_menu_2#}

<li><a href="{#text_sub_menu_2_.{$foo}}">{#text_sub_menu_2_.{$foo}}</a></li>
{/for}
```

I would like to take a dynamic parameter text_sub_menu_2_1 the second loop becomes text_sub_menu_2_2 etc.

someone knows how to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but you can try using `{counter}`

```
{for $foo=1 to #tot_sub_menu_2#}
{* initialize the count *}
{counter start=0 skip=1}
<li><a href="{#text_sub_menu_2_.{counter}}">{#text_sub_menu_2_.{counter}}</a></li>
```

Otherwise you can make use of the `@iteration` property. See http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration

> iteration contains the current loop iteration and always starts at
>   one, unlike index. **It is incremented by one on each iteration**.

```
{foreach from=$new_products item='product' name='newProducts'} 
// Do somthing 

//Here i want to increment {$count} if it's lower than 3 or set to 1 if higher than 3 
{if $product@iteration <= 3}{$count =  $product@iteration}{else}{$count = 1}{/if} 

{/foreach}
```